# What's the best option to store an encryption key for AES-256-CBC?

Tags: php, filesystems, aes

I am using PHP's openssl to encrypt sensitive user data on my website. I have an ssl certificate to provide further encryption. But how do I keep the key secure?

I have done some research and come up with these steps to follow-

1) Store it in another server. Away from the root folder.

2)Some row specific keys are kept in the database, but encrypted with a master key.

3) The master key isn't in the stored in the drive but rather kept on the ram.

4) Proper authentication of the key before usage.

But how do I ensure no one gets the master key?

I have 2 servers- A and B.
A contains the protected database, B has the master key. Now, A, when necessary will retrieve the key from B and store it in the ram, preferably as a variable.

How do I ensure no one gets the key at server B? Should I store it as a php file or some other format? If it's another format, how do I make sure only server A's decrypt.php can only read it and no one else can?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Keeping an encryption key secure is a very difficult problem. Generally the best you can do is make sure it is not in the http path and make the server as secure as possible. That includes two factor authentication and careful control of the second factor.

The only way to really keep the key secret is to insure it is never available and that would require a HSM [(Hardware Security Module)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module), a separate hardware device that performs the encryption/decryption so the key is never available. Think $5,000+.

Comment: The format is not particularly important. Keep in mind that the key is in memory when it is being used.

Comment: So does including a PHP page which contains the key as a variable safe?

Comment: Re a second server: You could setup a second server that does nothing but handle the encryption and is only on a local network (not connected to the Internet). Then the issue of keeping the key and encryption secure is limited to a server that has that one role.

Comment: I am getting a vps. Second server will still be connected to the internet.

Comment: You do not want the key in any file that could possible be accessed from the Internet.

Comment: If the second server is accessible from the Internet it i venerable without physical access and that reduces the security. You need to evaluate the potential attacker, their resources and how much they are willing to spend on an attack. How valuable your data is, assign a monetary amount to it. What is the attacker erases all you data. All security is just increasing the work factor to an attacker, nothing is 100% secure.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [AWS KMS](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/) or if you want to store some secrets on local premises, have a look at this open source project - [Hashicorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) - it is pretty nifty.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to protect your data from?

- If you are trying to protect it from a SQL injection attack, for instance, then having it encrypted "inside" the database may offer some help.
- If you are trying to protect it from someone who is attempting to gain privileged access to your web infrastructure it is an entirely different issue.

For example, if your servers have not been hacked and the code residing on the server has not been compromised, then if the software is doing it's job you'd be in a situation such that the software will decrypt only the data that the authenticated user is allowed to decrypt.

Generally, if someone gets privileged access to your server/code it may not make much difference where the key is stored. As noted by Zaph, leaving the web server unaware of encryption particulars by having a less accessible box sitting between the web server and the database may allow a higher level of security.

I'm doing something similar and will be using an AWS VPC to isolate sensitive/admin capabilities away from the web server. KMS will be used to keep the key encryption key opaque. Various types of monitoring will be performed and in the event an issue is detected the KMS key can be disabled - preventing access to data until the issue is resolved.